# php script connection error after sometime

Tags: php, sql, database

I am reading a csv file and updating a DB field on remote DB. I have about 1200 rows and after 750 rows I get this message

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\folder\file_name.php on line 53
Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Everytime this number is different means some times I am able to update 750 sometimes 800

```
    function unsubscribe($email_id, $created_at){
$servername1 = "name";
    $username1 = "name";
    $password1 = "pass";
    $dbname1 = "dbName";

    // Create connection
    $conn1 = mysqli_connect($servername1, $username1, $password1, $dbname1);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn1) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $timestamp = strtotime($created_at);
    $sql = "update email_list set unsubscribed = '" . $timestamp . "' where emailaddress = '" . $email_id . "'";
    echo "OnServer  Date = " . $created_at . " and Timestamp =  " . $timestamp . " and email = " . $email_id . "<br>";
    mysqli_query($conn1, $sql);
    mysqli_close($conn1);
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `sleep()` after about 500 rows, and reconnect to the server once the sleep is done. It will help reduce the load.

Comment: how do I add that? I am adding my code in the question above can you look at it and tell me

Comment: @aynber I have added my code in question

Comment: You'll want to do it inside of your foreach/while loop. Add a counter, and when the counter hit 500, do `sleep(5)`, or make it longer. You're opening/closing your connection each time, so you don't need to reconnect.